# Generate automatically Spring Data Repositories from JPA entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a lot of JPA entities automatically created from a relational database schema.

Is there any way to generate also there corresponding Spring Data Repositories (Repository interfaces)?

Comment: No. It is one line of code per repository.

Comment: If you use spring boot, use Spring Data Generator https://github.com/cmeza20/spring-data-generator Generates repositories when executing the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Spring Roo to create models and repositories by one command.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html

Comment: New Website for Spring Roo: https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Comment: can we use it in an existing project that is not created initially using Roo?

Answer (score 0):

Wel, it's not for `JPA`, but I created a tool, [EWA](https://marco-sulla.github.io/ewa/), for creating `Repositories`, `Services` and `Models` for `Spring Boot` + [sql2o](https://www.sql2o.org/), a simple db driver, the fastest after pure `JDBC`.